# Enum.reduce_while vs Enum.reduce in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am a beginner at Elixir. Here are my queries. I have written two functions below.

a) The first one uses `Enum.reduce_while`

b) the second function uses `Enum.reduce`

I am observing the following:
a) In the first function the count goes from 0, 1, 2, 3 and gets reset (Basically for each row, the count gets reset). This I could observe by viewing the output of `IO.puts` My expectation was that the "count" should keep incrementing.

b) However in the 2nd function the count keeps incrementing (which is expected). The only difference is that the first one is `reduce_while`, whereas the second one is just `reduce`.

Questions:

a) Why there is a difference in the way accumulators are treated between `Enum.reduce_while` vs `Enum.reduce`?

b) What am I missing?

```elixir
def is_power_pattern_present_in_grid(grid, pattern, max_row, max_col)
    when length(pattern) <= max_row * max_col do
  count = 0
  result = 0

  {chk, chk1} =
    Enum.reduce_while(0..(max_row - 1), {result, count}, fn row, {result, count} ->
      Enum.reduce_while(0..(max_col - 1), {result, count}, fn col, {result, count} ->
        IO.puts("looping throughat #{inspect(row)}, #{inspect(col)},#{inspect(count)}")
        count = count + 1
        result = 0
        {:cont, {result, count}}
      end)

      {:cont, {result, count}}
    end)
end

def is_power1_pattern_present_in_grid(grid, pattern, max_row, max_col)
    when length(pattern) <= max_row * max_col do
  count = 0
  result = 0

  {chk, chk1} =
    Enum.reduce(0..(max_row - 1), {result, count}, fn row, {result, count} ->
      Enum.reduce(0..(max_col - 1), {result, count}, fn col, {result, count} ->
        IO.puts("looping throughat #{inspect(row)}, #{inspect(col)},#{inspect(count)}")
        count = count + 1
        result = 0
        {result, count}
      end)
    end)
end
```

Comment: Please format your code as code, get rid of typographic quotes and `→` arrows and indent it in the first place.

Comment: Yes. just finished it.

Comment: @Sudarsan could you add an example dataset to test these functions with, please? So that it would be clear what is in, what is out (and what are your expectations of the latter :))

Comment: This is a very confusing way to pose the question, so I don't think you'll receive many responses. I would recommend you simplify this down to the bare essence of the problem, i.e. remove the nested Enum's, hard-code a sample value to operate on etc, and consider giving your accumulators distinct names, and then I think you will see the differences between the 2 functions or at least enable others to offer useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The outer reduces are returning different things. The bottom reduce is returning the result of the inner reduce while the top one is throwing away the result and returning `{0, 0}`.

Hopefully it is a bit easier to see with different variable names:

```elixir
def is_power_pattern_present_in_grid(grid, pattern, max_row, max_col)
    when length(pattern) <= max_row * max_col do
  initial_count = 0
  initial_result = 0

  {chk, chk1} =
    Enum.reduce_while(0..(max_row - 1), {initial_result, initial_count}, fn row, {outer_result, outer_count} ->
      Enum.reduce_while(0..(max_col - 1), {outer_result, outer_count}, fn col, {inner_result, inner_count} ->
        IO.puts("looping throughat #{inspect(row)}, #{inspect(col)},#{inspect(inner_count)}")
        inner_count = inner_count + 1
        inner_result = 0
        {:cont, {inner_result, inner_count}}
      end)

      {:cont, {outer_result, outer_count}}
    end)
end

def is_power1_pattern_present_in_grid(grid, pattern, max_row, max_col)
    when length(pattern) <= max_row * max_col do
  initial_count = 0
  initial_result = 0

  {chk, chk1} =
    Enum.reduce(0..(max_row - 1), {initial_result, initial_count}, fn row, {outer_result, outer_count} ->
      Enum.reduce(0..(max_col - 1), {outer_result, outer_count}, fn col, {inner_result, inner_count} ->
        IO.puts("looping throughat #{inspect(row)}, #{inspect(col)},#{inspect(inner_count)}")
        inner_count = inner_count + 1
        inner_result = 0
        {inner_result, inner_count}
      end)
    end)
end
```

This seems like what you may have intended:

```elixir
def is_power_pattern_present_in_grid(grid, pattern, max_row, max_col)
    when length(pattern) <= max_row * max_col do
  initial_count = 0
  initial_result = 0

  {chk, chk1} =
    Enum.reduce_while(0..(max_row - 1), {initial_result, initial_count}, fn row, {outer_result, outer_count} ->
      {result, count} = Enum.reduce_while(0..(max_col - 1), {outer_result, outer_count}, fn col, {inner_result, inner_count} ->
        IO.puts("looping throughat #{inspect(row)}, #{inspect(col)},#{inspect(inner_count)}")
        inner_count = inner_count + 1
        inner_result = 0
        {:cont, {inner_result, inner_count}}
      end)

      {:cont, {result, count}}
    end)
end
```